# add a node to specific child node

Tags: c#, treeview

I can add a node to a treeview add method.But I want to add a node to specific child node.
For example want to add a node to node5

```
|___node0
|___node1     
|     |___node3
|     |___node4
|           |___node5
|___node2
```

How do I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic recursive tree node searcher, of the top of my head. If you only need to search by key, the answer by weismat is the easiest, however if you need to search by the data on the nodes, you should consider this solution as you can replace the name search with whatever you might like to find.

```
private TreeNode FindNode(TreeNode root, String name)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            return FindNode(root, name);
        if (node.Name == name)
            return node;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand.How I use this method?And what this method give to me?Please help me with details.Thanks alot.

Comment: TreeNode node = FindNode(treeView1.Nodes[0], "node5")

Answer (score 5):

```
TreeNode[] tn = treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Find(search.Text, true);
if (tn.Count>0) 
   tn[0].Nodes.Add(node);
else
   //handle node not found
```

Comment: I had to set my add statement to `tn[0].Nodes.Add(node)` in order to get it working. Edited the answer above to reflect. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the child node reference , you can simply access its Nodes Collection and add new child into its collection as shown below

```
node5.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("temp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

William was right, but the method should look like this:

```
private TreeNode FindNode(TreeNode root, String name)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == name)
                    return node;
                else
                {
                    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                        return FindNode(node, name);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

tested this and works just fine,

Cheers!